# How to package and deploy a Youtbe API app to be used by other users

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, package, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I developped an application using youtube api and python. This application launchs live streams on my channel.
To do so I went to google console , and created "consent screen", "credentials"  downloaded "json auth file"....etc then developped my code in python , run it, everything works fine in my machine and on my channel
Now I want that this application to be used by some users (friends), so they can launch lives in their channels
Shall they create also consent screen ... because this too heavy , as consent screen asks for many details about developper profile. But the final users are not developpers

So please any exlanation on how to be able to use a youtube api app elsewhere

Comment: would you please add a [example] just so that we can see your code.  It may help others in the future to understand what type of application you have created currently wither it be installed app or web app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you give your script to others they will need to create their own project up on google cloud console. You can not share your client id and client secrete with others. Unless you can compile your python into an executable.  I believe that is possible.

If they don't want to create their own projects then you should host your script some place like a web page where they can then click on it authorize the app and create their live streams.  this will mean to switching to web application credentials, i am assuming you created a desktop app / native app currently.

If you go with option one the users are going to have to verify their apps themselves.  If you go with option two your going to have to verify the application run by others.